# C fwrite and file size

Tags: c, file, fopen, fwrite

I'm confused of a strange problem. When I make something like below:

```
FILE* fl;
int* d = new int[3];
d[0] = -3;
d[1] = -3;
d[2] = -3;

plik = fopen("E:\data.txt","r+b");
fwrite((char*)d, sizeof(int), sizeof(int)*3, fl);
fclose(fl);
system("pause");
```

It writes correctly some data to the file, witch I can clean in notepad and get 0B file size. But if I change -3 to -2:

```
FILE* fl;
int* d = new int[3];
d[0] = -2;
d[1] = -2;
d[2] = -2;

plik = fopen("E:\data.txt","r+b");
fwrite((char*)d, sizeof(int), sizeof(int)*3,fl);
fclose(fl);
system("pause");
```

the result is that, when I clean the data in Notepad and save file, it have always `2B`, and can't be cleaned to the end. What is the problem?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note `fwrite`, `fclose` etc are not C++, but C. Edited your question accordingly.

Comment: Change the path into `"E:\\data.txt"`. Otherwise, you might not open the correct file for writing.

Comment: @Qntm `new[]` operator is C++, not C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writing binary data to a file and then opening it with a text editor. The result is UNDEFINED. When you see that word "UNDEFINED" in documentation, pay attention. It is your responsibility to not do things like that. A text editor is for opening text files, which means strings. The way to write an int into a text file is to do something like:

```
char str[BIGNUMBER];
sprintf(str, "%d", d[0]);
fwrite...
```

That is probably not what you wanted but it is the only way to get a Notepad compatible text file. What you probably want to do is to find a binary file editor that can open, display and edit binary files. Personally I just use vim with the -b option, even on Windows.

Comment: This code doesn't do anything useful for me, just came across it while on the implementation of my project, where I lost 2 hours to handle what is making the problem and then I was curious about the reason for this. But I think you're right, thank you all for your help.

Comment: Not sure why you say it is "undefined"? The bytes in the file are known - and presumably, so is the behavior of a specific editor when such bytes are encountered. Quite likely they cannot be converted to a visible character - but that is different. What documentation are you referring to? Upvoting for generally identifying the root cause although I disagree with some of what you say.

Comment: @Floris, yes the bytes in the file are known and they do not follow the specification of a "text" file. Therefore the result of opening the file with some random text editor, which expects to load text files, is undefined. Try an experiment. Copy a PDF file and change the name to something.doc. Then load it in a word processor. Can you see the document on your screen?

Comment: Ah - the key is "with some random text editor". For a specific editor the behavior can be known, but not for "any" (for the reason you point out). I don't need to do the experiment you suggest - I know what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

The notepad is obviously confusing the data you're writing with [unicode byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) and gets into some funny state.

Consider how the data you're writing will look in binary and what it can possibly do to text editor.

Answer (score 1):

when you open file you assign it to variable name plik

```
plik = fopen("E:\data.txt","r+b");
```

but you write to variable fl which is uninitialized.

```
fwrite((char*)d, sizeof(int), sizeof(int)*3,fl);
```

And the size for write should not multiply with sizeof(int).

```
fwrite((char*)d, sizeof(int), 3,fl);
```

Comment: The `fl` is called `plik` in my code, I had a mistake when editing and pasting it here, and its not the problem. I changed `"E:\data.txt"`" to `"E:\\data.txt"` but it didnt help. Generally the problem is with the `-2` number, when I insert anything else in the code below, everything is fine:

`FILE* plik;
int d=-2;
int* a=&d;
 
plik=fopen("E:\\data.txt","r+b");
fwrite((char*)a,sizeof(int),sizeof(int),plik);
fclose(plik)`